# How to get all notifications for my app in notification center of iOS 5

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I use `didReceiveRemoteNotifications:(NSDictionary*)userInfo` to get a push message while it arrives.

The problem is:  iOS 5 added a notification center to temporarily save push notifications, when I tap one of them , the `didReceiveRemote**`  call back func only gets one of the messages, and other messages dissappear in notification center.

How can I get all of the push messages in the notification center?

Comment: Having the same issue. Currently my app can only handle the latest notification and clear the others by settings the badge number. Hope someone helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get all the messages in the notification center, is to have the user touch them.

When your app enters the foreground, it should check with the server for any unreceived messages.